# Error getting voice pricing for specific numbers

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am working on a Silex based web app that interacts with Twilio

I am trying to use twilio-php to retrieve pricing data from Twilio for outbound calls to specific phone numbers, but am running into an unexpected error.

The relevant portion of my code is:

```php
$client = new Pricing_Services_Twilio($accountSid, $authToken);
$priceData = $client->voiceNumbers->get($number);

$twigArgs = array(
    'number' => $priceData->number,
    'country' => $priceData->country,
    'isoCountry' => $priceData->iso_country,
    'priceUnit' => $priceData->price_unit,
    'outboundBasePrice' => $priceData->outbound_call_price->call_base_price,
    'outboundCurrentPrice' => $priceData->outbound_call_price->call_current_price,
    'inboundBasePrice' => $priceData->inbound_call_price->call_base_price,
    'inboundCurrentPrice' =>$priceData->inbound_call_price->call_current_price
);
```

This *seems* to be in keeping with the code sample in the [documentation](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/pricing.html#voice-numbers), but I keep getting the following exception (line number modified to match the correct line in the code snippet):

> ContextErrorException in index.php line 9: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$call_base_price

What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: I know that `$number` is correct, since I am able to retrieve `$priceData->number`, `$priceData->country`, `$priceData->iso_country`, and `$priceData->price_unit` without any problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ricky from Twilio here.

Looks like you found a bug in our documentation. You can access "base price" and "current price" like this:

```
$priceData->outbound_call_price->base_price;
$priceData->outbound_call_price->current_price;
```

Comment: As a quick note, you shouldn't add unnecessary commentary to your answer- Instead, it should be posted as a comment that you delete after the fact. For instance, you could have commented about the shirt offer on the question here, or on your answer itself. Preferably, you could've invited the OP to chat and offered there, as well.